# Latest Netbeans for tomcat6

Tags: netbeans, tomcat6

I wish to do several changes to app running on tomcat6 what version of Netbeans should get?

Netbeans 6.0? 
6.1, 6.5, 6.9 ?
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/install.html